# Why can I not log in to Stack Overflow with Google Chrome on a Mac?

Tags: support, login, google-chrome

As a user I would like to be able to log in to your website with Google Chrome so I can ask questions.

Scenario: Log in with Chrome

- Given I am on a Mac
- And I am using the latest Google Chrome browser
- And I am on the StackOverflow homepage
- When I follow "log in"
- And I fill in "openid_identifier" with "delescluze.myopenid.com"
- And I press "Log in"
- Then I should be redirected to the open id provider's website

Instead of the above, I remain on the login page. The button is not disabled. No errors in JS console.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is happening that is blocking you from logging in? Are you receiving an error? Is it kicking you out? Was the "login" link obliterated?

Comment: What version of google chrome is this?

Comment: it's probably your openid provider, not stackoverflow, that's the problem

Comment: I'll add a scenario above.

Comment: Also, if the problem is my openid provider, it's probably StackOverflow's problem as far as they rely on them to have users log in :-)

Comment: can you try with a non-beta browser? We only support *released* web browsers for our own sanity. (and just so you know, Chrome betas have a long history of fairly serious issues on our sites)

Comment: I do use Safari. Just had wanted to give you guys a heads up.

Comment: For Chrome users, I don't think there is a non-beta version of Chrome.  I am using the version available for download from http://www.google.com/chrome.  Also, Google keeps software in beta forever -- Gmail started on 21 March 2004 as beta and became a release on 7 July 2009.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I didn't have it on my old Macbook. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

This should work fine -- you can email us via the address at the bottom of every page with specifics, we can help.

edit: apparently Chrome 5 is rigidly enforcing the "must be URI" designator on the input box rather than treating it as an input aid. **MAKE SURE YOU ENTER HTTP://** in this box if you are on Chrome 5.0.

Comment: Seems to be the correct behaviour by HTML5. However, any kind of user notice would be nice.

Comment: Agreed -- since the fix is now known, how about some javascript validation message?

Comment: Update -- seems to work ok for me now on meta and SO, but not on area51

Answer (score 2):

I am currently on a Mac, logged in, using Google Chrome.

Comment: Same here, it just works

Comment: Not on Mac, logged in, using IE -- can I get some rep, too?  :-)

Comment: Wow I guess if it didn't work, I wouldn't be able to post this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.  I could not log in to Stack Overflow with Chrome on OS X by typing myOpenId URL and then clicking the Log in button.  However, from the Stack Overflow login page, I could:

1. click the myOpenId icon above the login box
2. enter myOpenId username in the new box that appeared
3. click the Sign In button to login successfully

Maybe there is some sort of JavaScript issue with submission or the large Log in button...?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Clicking the login button simply puts focus back on the input field.

The workaround is simply to answer a question somewhere and logging in that way around.